# What is DotNetCore VS2015 preview tool

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

Am starting to learn DotNet core and i was following the tools needed for the same. I read that after installing VS 2015 I need to install DotNetCore VS2015  preview tool.

What is the need got this preview tool. Can some one help me in understanding what is the need for the same

Comment: Why use VS2015 which doesn't properly support .NET Core, when VS2017 does? (In particular, I wouldn't expect any such "preview" addition to support the .NET Core 2.0 SDK which would be a better idea to learn about than 1.0.)

Comment: It is good to download VS2017 community edition in that you can also work with .Net Core 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *“.NET Core Visual Studio 2015 Tooling Preview”* was a preview addon for Visual Studio 2015 to support the new tooling that came with early versions of .NET Core. This tooling was based on `project.json` files and the new `dotnet` executable.

Since then, the tooling around .NET Core has been changed again to make use of MSBuild and the `.csproj` files that already existed before. The `.csproj` format has been changed to be a lot more flexible and easier to read thanks to the new *Microsoft.NET.Sdk* project type.

This new project format is the recommended way to work with .NET Core 1.1 projects and is the *only* way to make .NET Core projects starting with 2.0. Unfortunately, Visual Studio only started to support that new format starting with Visual Studio 2017.

So Visual Studio 2015 cannot be used to create *current* .NET Core projects. The tooling preview was only there to add support to the older project format which has since been discontinued.

Since using .NET Core 2 is a much better idea than using older versions of it, I would recommend you to upgrade to Visual Studio 2017 to start developing with .NET Core. Alternatively, you could also look into Visual Studio Code which is a more lightweight alternative to create .NET Core projects and also fully supports the current project format.